# Running a certain XCOPY command without user interaction

Tags: windows-7, command-line, xcopy

I am trying to run the following command in Windows CLI:

```
XCOPY Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE%\_vimrc /H
```

The `/H` part needs to be there because `Z:\.vimrc` is a hidden file.

When I run the command above, I get the following message:

```
Does C:\Users\Matt\_vimrc specify a file name
or directory name on target
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

This command will eventually be part of a BAT file and I don't want that prompt. The answer to it is always "F".

If `.vimrc` and `_vimrc` were named the same, I could just run one of these commands and be done with it:

```
XCOPY Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE%\ /H
XCOPY Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE% /H /I
```

But they are not, so I can't. How do I suppress that message?

I know I could copy it with the same file name and then move it, but c'mon, does this really have to be two commands? I'm just copying a file.

Note: When there is already a `%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc` file, the message does not appear.

Comment: It's been a long time and I'm on Linux but xcopy /s/v/e/H brings back memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh.

```
echo F | XCOPY Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE%\_vimrc /H
```

Comment: So glad I replaced Windows with Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Hack:

```
type Z:\.vimrc > "%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot see the problem with renaming afterwards

```
xcopy Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE%\ /H && ren %USERPROFILE%\.vimrc _vimrc
```

If there is a possibility of the file existing already:

```
if NOT EXIST %USERPROFILE%\_vimrc (
    xcopy Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE%\ /H && ren %USERPROFILE%\.vimrc _vimrc
) ELSE (
    del %USERPROFILE%\_vimrc
    xcopy Z:\.vimrc %USERPROFILE%\ /H && ren %USERPROFILE%\.vimrc _vimrc
)
```

Comment: Seems really kludgy. Also, what if `%USERPROFILE%\.vimrc` existed already?

Comment: @mattalexx: I just edited my answer. I'm not sure what you want to do if the file exists, but you get the drift.  I don't think it's kludgy, as one has to do stuff like that all the time with CMD

Comment: You are duplicating the same `xcopy && ren` line in both "if" and "else" blocks. This could be changed to `if exist ... del ...` and `xcopy ... && ren ...`, which is much shorter.

Comment: @grawity: Fair point, but if you look at the edits, you'll see why I was not thinking of that.  I wasn't really sure what he wanted to when the file exists already.